# Two div that fit the content height

Tags: html, css

I have a div (`.main-div`) that contains two inner div (`.title-div` and `.body-div`).
They must fit in both direction the size of `.main-div`.

`.title-div` has a fixed height of `25px`.

Sometimes `.title-div` can be hidden. But when I do that my `.body-div` goes up but doesn't fit `.main-div` because its height property is wrong.

I would like my `.body-div` always fit the available space of its parent

```css
.main-div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.title-div {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.body-div {
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
/* from bootstrap*/

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="title-div">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="body-div">
    body
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/g8zef0ux/

Any ideas?

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/g8zef0ux/1/ ?

Comment: try flex-box, this has been explained over and over already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: I have added a solution to you problem so one button can toggle the title and the height of body updates correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do. Here are two possible solutions.

In my first example, at the same time you're hiding the title, we're adding an additional class to the body so that it's taller. It overwrites your calc, and sets the height to 100%.

In the second example, we use the CSS3 Flexbox module to cause the body to grow to fill all available space. When the title is there, it's set to not grow, not shrink, and stay at 25px, and the body fills the rest. When the title is gone, the body fills the whole space available.

```js
$(".btn1").click(function() {
 $(".title-div1").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".body-div1").toggleClass("body-div-noTitle");
});

$(".btn2").click(function() {
 $(".title-div2").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.main-div1 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title-div1 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.body-div1 {
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.body-div-noTitle {
  height:100%;
}

.main-div2 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.title-div2 {
  flex: 0 0 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.body-div2 {
  flex:1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

/* from bootstrap*/
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div main-div1">
  <div class="title-div  title-div1">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="body-div body-div1">
    body
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<input class="btn1" type="button" value="Toggle title visibility" />

<div class="main-div main-div2">
  <div class="title-div  title-div2">
    title
  </div>
  <div class="body-div body-div2">
    body
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<input class="btn2" type="button" value="Toggle title visibility" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily achieve this with flexbox.
https://jsfiddle.net/g8zef0ux/2/

```
.main-div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.title-div {
  flex: 0 0 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.body-div {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i think you are asking here is the solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/g8zef0ux/

I added a check to see if it contained the hidden class by doing so:

```
if (!$(".title-div").hasClass('hidden')) {
    $(".body-div").css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=25px');
    }else{
    $(".body-div").css('height', '100%');
  }
```

If true adjust the height accordingly.